# "Freely positionable" Videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, mencoder

The following is a requirement for loading a video into National Instruments DIAdem: 
`The videos must be freely positionable, so that DIAdem can display each frame in the videos.` [Video - DIAdem 2012 Help - National Instruments](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370858K-01/genview/genview/view_video/)

What does *freely positionable* mean in terms of video encoding (specifically using ffmpeg or mencoder)?

Comment: Context wise the only thing I thought of was if somehow it was impossible to start from an arbitrary frame... but I don't know if  AVI has a frame-lock mechanism (i.e. force you to start from the beginning).

Comment: @DoktoroReichard, that’s a good guess and certainly makes sense, but I would think that the term *freely-seekable* would be better in that case. If National Instruments were a little, a foreign company, then I could forgive a poor choice of English words, [but they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Instruments) [are not](http://www.ni.com/company/), so if you are correct, then it means poor copy-editing on their part. ¬_¬

Comment: You may have to ask them to translate their proprietary speak. Perhaps it refers to [intra-only formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Intra-only) (try the `-g 0` option in ffmpeg).

Comment: The fact that they specify that the videos need to be in "MPEG and AVI formats" means that they have no idea what they're talking about. But I'd say the "freely positionable" means seekable in some way.